# Django ManyToManyField информация из связанной модели в шаблоне

Tags: django, шаблоны, many-to-many, field

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести информацию из связанной модели в шаблоне?

models

```
class Cars(models.Model):
brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Engine(models.Model):
engine = models.CharField(max_length=30)
cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars, verbose_name="cars", related_name='cars_rn')
```

views

```
class EngineView(DetailView):
model = Engine
template_name = 'cars/engine_detail.html'
slug_field = 'engine_url'
```

template

```
{% block content %}

{{ engine.engine }} <! -- Работает -->

{% for car in engine.cars_rn.all %} 
   {{ car.brand }} <! -- Не работает -->
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не поняли логику related_name. В related_name вы указываете имя "обратного обращения", то есть из Cars к Engine.
Таким образом, ваш класс Engine должен выглядеть так:

```
class Engine(models.Model):
engine = models.CharField(max_length=30)
cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars, verbose_name="cars", related_name='engines')
```

Теперь вы можете писать так:

```
car.engines.all()
```

И это будет работать.

Чтобы сделать выборку всех Car из Engine, нужно писать так:

```
{% for car in engine.cars.all %} 
    {{ car.brand }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% for car in engine.cars.all %} 
    {{ car.brand }}
{% endfor %} - здесь "engine"  - это название класса получается, а не related_name? (пытаюсь понять)

Comment: @ArgumentSite, здесь engine это объект, который ты передаешь в контексте.

Например вот так: `context = {'engine': Engine.objects.get(id=1)}`

А контекст ты потом передаешь в html шаблон, в котором уже происходит вышеописанное.

Comment: Так, а если применительно к  View, а к DetailView, где нет "context", как тогда получается?

Comment: @ArgumentSite, там есть контекст, читайте [документацию](https://djbook.ru/rel1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-display.html#adding-extra-context). Просто если вы не прописываете метод вручную, то берется объект переданного класса.